# iOS Charts How to set min and max values flexibly

Tags: ios, swift, charts

[image]

I am trying to output a histogram like the picture above.

[image]

Sometimes the output comes out normally, but sometimes it doesn't come out properly.

```
cell.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum
cell.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum
```

So, I used the method to set the Maximum and Minimum. However, even if you use it, it does not output properly in all situations. Positive and negative numbers I wonder if there is a way or expression to set the min and max values and not go over the graph screen in a situation where both large and small numbers can come out.

```
        if maxValue < 0 && minValue < 0 {
            cell.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 0
            cell.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = minValue + (minValue * 0.2)
        } else if maxValue >= 0 && minValue >= 0 {
            cell.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = maxValue + (maxValue * 0.1)
            cell.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
        } else if maxValue == 0 && minValue == 0 {
            cell.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 100
        } else if maxValue >= 0 && minValue < 0  {
            cell.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = maxValue + (maxValue * 0.06)
            cell.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = minValue + (minValue * 2.17)
        }
```

I tried the following expression, but it doesn't work in all situations... Is there a way to display up and down in all situations?

minValue, maxValue This is the value I found in my data list.

iOS-Charts Version - 3.5.0

Comment: Is this the new Swift Charts API (iOS 16) or something else?

Comment: @aheze ios-Charts Library https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts